# Testing vue3 computed properties with TypeScript SFC

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I am trying to write a test, using [vitest](https://vitest.dev/), to assert a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) in a vue3 component that is defined with [script setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html).

Consider a simple component:

```html
// simple.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';

const hello = computed((): string => {
  return 'Hello';
});
</script>

<template>
  {{ hello }}
</template>
```

My test is like this:

```
describe('Hello', () => {
  it('should compute hello', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Hello);
    expect(wrapper.vm.hello).toBe('Hello');
  });
});
```

This test actually works as expected when run using `vitest`, so functionally things seem to be working well.

However, VSCode cannot see the computed properties on the `vm` object:

[image]

It *is* able to see normal properties (e.g., those defined with the `defineProps` macro). Is this just a problem with VSCode-specific tooling, or is there another way I should be going about testing computed properties in vue3 components?

If this is the preferred method, is there a way to pull in the types of the computed properties (similar to how the types of the defined props seem to be pulled in)?

I have tried the technique described in this [Vue Testing Handbook](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/computed-properties.html#testing-with-call), but this doesn't work at all and I assume it must be specific to vue2.

Comment: It's totally possible because IDE, test rig and main setup has a different toolchain and don't behave similarly. It's a problem that comp API prefers FP and won't expose anything you need to test to the instance. Graybox testing with Vue Testing Library is preferable to not be limited with this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose):

> Components using `<script setup>` are **closed by default** - i.e. the public instance of the component, which is retrieved via template refs or `$parent` chains, will not expose any of the bindings declared inside `<script setup>`.

This also affects the type of the `wrapper.vm` in Vue Test Utils, such that it only includes public or *exposed* props of the `<script setup>` component.

In your case, use the `defineExpose()` compiler macro to expose `hello`:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';

const hello = computed((): string => {
  return 'Hello';
});
     
defineExpose({ hello });
</script>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the `mount` you are using is from `@vue/test-utils`.
You can type the wrapper like this to have typescript autocompletion and don't have errors:

```
import {mount, VueWrapper} from "@vue/test-utils";
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue"
import { ComponentPublicInstance } from "vue";

type MyComponentProps = any
type MyComponentVariables = {
  hello: string
}

type MyComponentWrapperType = VueWrapper<ComponentPublicInstance<MyComponentProps, MyComponentVariables>>

describe('Hello', () => {
  it('should compute hello', () => {
    const wrapper: MyComponentWrapperType = mount(HelloWorld);
    expect(wrapper.vm.hello).toBe('Hello');
  });
});
```

The first generic type (here I put `any`) are the props type of your component and the second generic ({ bipbip: string }) are the types of your returned properties (what you return in a `setup` function). With `<script setup>` you can put directly all your variables.

Comment: This is helpful to point in the direction of how to properly, but manually, set the type of the returned wrapper. I have yet to get it to work with a non-trivial component but I'll play around with it. I'm still holding out hope for a way to get the computed properties inferred automatically, just like the "normal" props are.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I hope `@vue/test-utils` will upgrade this